Terraform not re-creating OPTIONS integration responses for API Gateway
I am using Terraform to deploy a series of lambdas attached to API Gateway endpoints and am trying to overcome CORS issues. I have not been able to make the CORS work except to manually do it through the console after applying Terraform. That's tolerable, but what I'm seeing is that when I create the OPTIONS method with a Response and Integration Response, it intermittently wipes out the headers that it previously put for them. I believe it is re-creating the method but not re-running the response stuff again. I'm not at all sure this is something I am doing wrong, but if anyone has a suggestion on how to "force" terraform to re-run blocks, I would surely like to know. Here's my code.
data "archive_file" "subscription_subscription_price" {
  type = "zip"

  source_dir  = "${path.module}/functions/subscription-subscription-price"
  output_path = "${path.module}/subscription-subscription-price.zip"
}

resource "aws_s3_object" "subscription_subscription_price" {    
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.xxxxx-deployment-subscription-api-pipeline.id

  key    = "${var.archive_path}/subscription-subscription-price.zip"
  source = data.archive_file.subscription_subscription_price.output_path

  etag = filemd5(data.archive_file.subscription_subscription_price.output_path)
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "subscription_subscription_price_lambda" {
  function_name = "subscription-subscription-price"

  s3_bucket = aws_s3_bucket.xxxxx-deployment-subscription-api-pipeline.id
  s3_key    = aws_s3_object.subscription_subscription_price.key

  runtime = "nodejs18.x"
  handler = "index.handler"

  source_code_hash = data.archive_file.subscription_subscription_price.output_base64sha256

  role = aws_iam_role.lambda_exec_s3.arn
}


resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_group" "subscription_subscription_price" {
  name = "/aws/lambda/${aws_lambda_function.subscription_subscription_price_lambda.function_name}"
  retention_in_days = 14
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "subscription_price_resource_proxy" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.subscription_api.id
  parent_id   = aws_api_gateway_resource.subscription_price_resource.id
  path_part   = "{type+}"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "subscription_subscription_price_method" {
  rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.subscription_api.id
  resource_id   = aws_api_gateway_resource.subscription_price_resource_proxy.id
  http_method   = "GET"
  authorization = "COGNITO_USER_POOLS"
  authorizer_id = aws_api_gateway_authorizer.cognito_authorizer.id
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "subscription_api_integration_subscription_subscription_price" {
  rest_api_id             = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.subscription_api.id
  resource_id             = aws_api_gateway_resource.subscription_price_resource_proxy.id
  http_method             = aws_api_gateway_method.subscription_subscription_price_method.http_method
  integration_http_method = "POST"
  type                    = "AWS_PROXY"
  uri                     = aws_lambda_function.subscription_subscription_price_lambda.invoke_arn
  
  request_templates = {
    "application/json" = jsonencode(
      {
        statusCode = 200
      }
    )
  }
}

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "subscription_api_gw_subscription_subscription_price" {
  statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromAPIGateway"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.subscription_subscription_price_lambda.function_name
  principal     = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"

  source_arn = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.subscription_api.execution_arn}/*/*"
}


resource "aws_api_gateway_method_response" "subscription_subscription_price_response" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.subscription_api.id
  resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.subscription_price_resource_proxy.id
  http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.subscription_subscription_price_method.http_method
  status_code = 200

  //cors section
  response_parameters = {
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers" = true,
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods" = true,
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = true
  }

}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration_response" "subscription_subscription_price_integration_response" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.subscription_api.id
  resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.subscription_price_resource_proxy.id
  http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.subscription_subscription_price_method.http_method
  status_code = 200

  //cors
  response_parameters = {
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers" =  "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'",
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods" = "'GET,OPTIONS,POST,PUT,DELETE'",
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "'*'"
  }

  depends_on = [
    aws_api_gateway_method.subscription_subscription_price_method,
    aws_api_gateway_integration.subscription_api_integration_subscription_subscription_price
  ]
}



resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "subscription_subscription_price_options_method" {
  rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.subscription_api.id
  resource_id   = aws_api_gateway_resource.subscription_price_resource_proxy.id
  http_method   = "OPTIONS"
  authorization = "NONE"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "subscription_subscription_price_options_integration" {
  rest_api_id             = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.subscription_api.id
  resource_id             = aws_api_gateway_resource.subscription_price_resource_proxy.id
  http_method             = aws_api_gateway_method.subscription_subscription_price_options_method.http_method
  integration_http_method = "OPTIONS"
  type                    = "MOCK"
  
  request_templates = {
    "application/json" = jsonencode(
      {
        statusCode = 200
      }
    )
  }
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method_response" "subscription_subscription_price_options_response" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.subscription_api.id
  resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.subscription_price_resource_proxy.id
  http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.subscription_subscription_price_options_method.http_method
  status_code = 200

  response_models = {
    "application/json" = "optionsresponsemodel"
  }
  //cors section
  response_parameters = {
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers" = true,
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods" = true,
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = true
  }
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration_response" "subscription_subscription_price_options_integration_response" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.subscription_api.id
  resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.subscription_price_resource_proxy.id
  http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.subscription_subscription_price_options_method.http_method
  status_code = 200

  //cors
  response_parameters = {
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers" = "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'",
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods" = "'GET,OPTIONS,POST,PUT'",
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "'*'"
  }

  depends_on = [
    aws_api_gateway_method.subscription_subscription_price_options_method,
    aws_api_gateway_integration.subscription_subscription_price_options_integration,
    aws_api_gateway_method_response.subscription_subscription_price_options_response,
    aws_api_gateway_integration_response.subscription_subscription_price_options_integration_response
  ]
}

